# Can you only export objects to Second Life with 2.79?

Tags: export

Next week I begin teaching Blender fundamentals to an international group of Second Life players who wish to create assets for the game. One of the members has pointed out that 2.79 has an **Export To SL** feature that isn’t available in the later 2.8x versions. She believes I should teach them 2.79 because the lack of this feature will, either directly or indirectly, prohibit assets from being exported into the game. Is this the case? I would *much* rather teach on the latest build. I’m not a Second Life player myself, so please pardon my lack of understanding in this area. So—you can export assets to SL with 2.8x, right?

Thank you for your time,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Collada exporter.

You'll find it in the *File/Export* menu.

[image]

Which opens to this:

[image]

If the options panel is not open, use the <kbd>N</kbd> key to make it appear on the right:

[image]

And that gives you access to the OpenSim presets:

[image]

Source from [Machinimatrix](https://avastar.machinimatrix.org/279/knowledge/blender-2-8-news/) (Gaia Clary Avastar website).

Comment: Oh wow, excellent answer. Thank you so much!